# SAS SQL : Date compare

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

Hi i have a question for comparing two dates in SAS Proc SQL

-Condition-

Date_A(Fixed) : 2020-11-08

Date_B : 2020-12-15 or 2020-12-UN => Date_B Could be 2020-12-UN (UNknown Day)

So, what i did is...

```
Select A.DATE, B.DATE
From A.TABLE, B.TABLE
Where (input(Scan(Date_B,2,'-'),best10.) < input(Scan(Date_A,2,'-',best10.)) or Date_B < Date_A
```

-First, If Date_B's Day is 'UN', Compare with 'Month' If not simple compare..

But..its not working (even know why)

Is there any other way..?

with kind regards

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Are both variables character?  The second must be character as strings with UN in them cannot represent an actual date.  But the first might be a numeric variable with date values that is being displayed using the YYMMDD10. format so they look like the string you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps, though its possible your question isn't specific enough in detail... this will compare the dates as requested, but is unlikely to give you useful output (!)
This assumes the dates are strings, given the "UN" element.

`Select case when substr(A.DATE,9)='UN' then substr(A.DATE,1,7)`
            `else  A.DATE end  as DATE_A`
     `, case when length(calculated DATE_A)=7 then substr(B.DATE,1,7)`
            `else  B.DATE end  as DATE_B`
`From A.TABLE, B.TABLE`
`where calculated DATE_A < calculated DATE_B`